# How one can write $\bar{\psi}$ in odd dimension?

Tags: spacetime-dimensions, fermions, dirac-equation, spinors, dirac-matrices

I know that the Dirac equation in general dimensions has a form of 
$$
(i\gamma_{\mu} \nabla_\mu - m ) \psi =0
$$
and the action for that is written as 
$$
S = \int d^d x \bar{\psi} (i\gamma_{\mu} \nabla_\mu - m ) \psi
$$

Here I know that, in even dimensions,
$$
\bar{\psi} = \psi^{\dagger} \gamma^0
$$

Does it hold for odd dimensions?

This question was motivated from thinking about anomalies in even dimensions, and the different charge conjugation properties in even and odd dimension.

---

The defintion of $\bar{\psi}=\psi^{\dagger}\gamma^0$ holds only in Minkowski spacetime.(In other words, it is ill-defined in Euclidean spacetime.- recently someone tolds to me...) I heard that in Euclidean spacetime, the situation is complicated.

Is there anyone knows about the case of $\bar{\psi}$ in Euclidean spacetime?

Comment: Why do you think it would hold only in even dimensions? Charge conjugation as such has nothing to do with the conjugate spinor $\bar\psi$, which is just the proper notion of "complex conjugate in the contexts of spinors".

Comment: @ACuriousMind, I only know the examples for even dimension. Today I try to work the action for 3d, 5d, fermionic action and got confused about the case for odd dimension

Comment: Perhaps [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-dimensional_gamma_matrices#Generic_odd_d_.3D_2k_.2B_1) would be helpful to you?

Comment: First, my guess was same things could happens to odd dimension, but one of my friend told me due to charge conjugation properties, anomalies, it seems odd dimension has different property

Comment: But *what* confuses you? The definition $\bar\psi = \psi^\dagger\gamma^0$ can be made in any dimension, because $\gamma^0$ can always be taken to be the [reality structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reality_structure) of the spinor space.

Comment: @ACuriousMind, You are right. My first thought was similar as yours (but lack of logic), but i am not sure. So i post it a question. Now i can talk to my friend. Thanks!.

Comment: In odd dimensions the mass term breaks $P,T$. That's related to parity anomaly.